# How to make unlimited mobile hotspot trick work on linux?

Tags: networking, dual-boot, internet, connection

I recently dual booted into ubuntu because my Windows os is very slow to multitask. Surprisingly, when I tested most of my workspace in ubuntu, it can handle them very well than windows did (basically alt tabbing in windows took ages alongside the not responding message).

Now I planned to change my main os to linux but I ran into trouble when I wanted to do the unlimited hotspot trick on linux. I've been using this trick since forever because it actually works in Windows where I nearly *used 20gb of data on the laptop where it left my hotspot quota still unscathed.*

**Basically what I typed in the command line in Windows is:**

```
netsh int ipv4 set glob defaultcurhoplimit=65
netsh int ipv6 set glob defaultcurhoplimit=65
```

**It doesn't work on linux but I already did some research:**

```
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.all.hop_limit=65
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_default_ttl=65
```

I have tested playing some videos on youtube and finding that my quota is being used so *clearly this is not working.* I don't really want to invest in home wifi but take advantage that this trick exist.

**Has anyone done this trick or make this trick works in Linux?**

Answer (score 1):

Found an answer here:
https://www.reddit.com/r/Android/comments/cmxp66/2019_bypass_verizon_hotspot_throttle_no_root/

Answer:

```
sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_default_ttl=65
```

Another answer (ipv6):

```
sudo sysctl net.ipv6.conf.all.hop_limit=65
```

Found a separate answer here:
https://pmurphs.com/2021/02/14/change-ttl-on-windows-linux/

Answer:

```
sudo sysctl net.ipv4.ip_default_ttl=129
```

Another answer:

```
net.ipv4.ip_default_ttl=129
```